# Dismiss keyboard on rotate

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am looking at adding an observer to the listen for the orientation changed notification. What I want to do is dismiss the keyboard if it is currently up.

I cant see to be able to find an example that does not involve finding the individual control that has focus.

Comment: What's the issue... Is your notification working? And what do you mean by individual control that has focus?

Comment: Yes, I get the notification. But at that point, how can I "globally" dismiss the keyboard if it is present?

Comment: You're getting a lot of answers here, but at the risk of sounding arrogant, I think mine is what you're looking for in this case. I'd recommend checking it out first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your editing field is a subview of self.view, you can dismiss the keyboard regardless of its responder using:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: @CrimsonChris I'll add that for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

just call resignFirstResponder from your UITextField object, e.g.:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implementing an observer have you considered the following [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{  
    // dismiss keyboard (if it was presented via a textField, etc.
    [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];

    // or
    // [self.view endEditing:YES]; 

    // you can check for specific orientation via UIInterfaceOrientation - for example
    // landscape
    if (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        // do something
    }

}
```